# Need Help To Protect my MVC PHP app folder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an issue with my .htaccess.

Let's say that my app folder are:

```
/APP/
/CONTENT/
/UPLOADS/
/ASSETS/
```

And I have a .htaccess file that point all requests to my index.php, and the index php there is an included file called router.php that manage my roots:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

What i would want to do right now is to point APP and CONTENT folder also to the .htaccess and like that, i can display my custom 404 error page.

Comment: you should create a `pub/` folder which contains the front-end jazz that references the other folders - sidenote: why are you directories in caps?

Comment: Move the `APP` folder above the `www` or `public_html` folder (WebRoot), then leave `index.php` inside the WebRoot.  Keep your `ASSETS` which I assume has the `CSS`, `JS`